# Connecting to a MySQL database using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a mobile application using AngularJS and Ionic Framework. However, I'm lost when trying to find a solution for backend database support. Is there a plugin or third-party API available to use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client side web applications do not connect directly to SQL database servers.

You need to pick a server side programming language and write a web service interface to your database.

Then access that interface using XMLHttpRequest (which Angular wraps with [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)).

Comment: Take a look at [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) or [io.js](https://iojs.org/en/index.html) to run JavaScript on the server. There is a [package for mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

Comment: node.js is awesome! we run our company app with a backend node server that runs in IIS and connects to sql database.

Comment: I was thinking of creating an API in php but im not sure how the data would be sent back to a angularjs controller,. Im familiar with the $http.post('script.php' etc etc) setup to send data and execute however i cant seem to retrieve the information back for things like SELECT queries.

Comment: @DezmenCeoSykes — `<?php echo $somedata; ?>`